# How to load part of excel file name in SSIS

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I am loading multiple excel files consisting of monthly data in SQL datawarehouse through ssis.
i need month and year part from file name and fill a column with it. Name and path of my file are as

My File 09 2014 data.xls
C:\Mydata\My File 09 2014 data.xls

I need to load "09 2014" from it. Please guide how can i achieve this.

Rosh

Answer (score 1):

In the ForEachLoop which is used to process multiple files, the file name which is being processed currently can be stored in a Variable. With the variable having the file name, use it in a script task to modify/trim the unwanted part.